# Multisite missing tmp folder error while uploading

Tags: multisite, uploads

I have a multisite setup on a server that requires me to upload to a stage server then send a "publishnow.txt" file over to send everything to the production server. This is a state agency hence the extra steps in getting core file changes made and live on the web. This is very new to me having always worked with hosts like Godaddy.

I am having the hardest time configuring my tmp folder in order to upload any media to either of my 2 sites. I am getting the usual error of

> “image.jpg” has failed to upload due to an error. Missing a temporary
>   folder.

when I try to upload anything. My host has a public_html folder and a tmp folder in the root. I would love to tell Wordpress to use the tmp folder from the root, but I don't know if I need to write that in the wp-config.php file, the .htaccess file (which I cannot edit as the host says they do not parse that file) or something in the network settings within WP.

I am lost and losing time and patience is dwindling with my client. Perhaps someone with a clearer head could imaging the situation and advise me what I should try.

Thank you!

Comment: Wouldn't PHP/Apache determine the /tmp/ folder?

Comment: I think this is true, but do I need to place something like 'define('WP_TEMP_DIR', ABSPATH . 'tmp');' in the wp-config file?

Comment: apparently there IS a WP_TEMP_DIR define

Answer (score 1):

As this sounds like an existing WordPress setup that 'was' working and now 'is not' working then check a couple of things:
1. have you recently moved server? or who else has changed anything on your server such as:
- file permissions for the WordPress folder - have these change?
- php.ini or .htaccess files - has anyone deleted these?
- server vhost or httpd.conf files - were these changed

I'd follow these instructions which I found from a quick Google on the error:

> If you are receiving this error please follow these simple  instructions below:
>
> 1. Create a "tmp" folder in your WordPress root directory with 777 permissions. This can be done by your FTP program.
>
>    1. Also create a "php.ini" file in same location.
> 2. Add the following in php.ini file:
>
>    upload_max_filesize = 16M
>      upload_tmp_dir = on
>      upload_tmp_dir = /home/username/public_html/wordpressDir/tmp
>
>    Please make sure to replace username with your hosting username, and wordpressDir with the directory name of your WordPress install.
>      If you have installed WordPress on your homepage then the path will be like:   upload_tmp_dir = /home/username/public_html/tmp
> 3. Copy the same php.ini file to your wp_admin folder.

[source: FastWebHost](http://support.fastwebhost.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/322/26/wordpress-is-giving-error-missing-a-temporary-folder--while-uploading-imagemedia)

Comment: My host tech has added the required WP network code to the vhost config file is all I'm aware of.